# What does 'that' refer to in this passage?

Tags: anaphora

What does 'that' refer to in this passage?

> But the reason she was unavailable to speak with me is that she was
>   out for a hike, because it was a beautiful spring morning, and she
>   wanted to go for a hike. So of course this makes me even more
>   intrigued, and when I finally do catch up with her, she explains it
>   like this. She says, "Listen Laura, everything I do, every minute I
>   spend, is my choice." And rather than say, "I don't have time to do x,
>   y or z," she'd say, "I don't do x, y or z because it's not a
>   priority." "I don't have time," often means "It's not a priority." If
>   you think about it, that's really more accurate language. I could tell
>   you I don't have time to dust my blinds, but that's not true. If you
>   offered to pay me $100,000 to dust my blinds, I would get to it pretty
>   quickly.
>
> Since **that** is not going to happen, I can acknowledge this is not a
>   matter of lacking time; it's that I don't want to do it. Using this
>   language reminds us that time is a choice. And granted, there may be
>   horrible consequences for making different choices, I will give you
>   that. But we are smart people, and certainly over the long run, we
>   have the power to fill our lives with the things that deserve to be
>   there.

Answer (score 3):

It refers to the example of a situation that someone will offer to pay you some interesting amount of money to do such thing.
To be specific, it is this sentence.

> If you offered to pay me $100,000 to dust my blinds, I would get to it pretty quickly.

Therefore, it means that since this situation is not going to happen, I can acknowledge this is not a matter of lacking time

Answer (score 0):

"That" is a pronoun. [Specifically](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/that) in this case,

> 1.(used to indicate a person, thing, idea, state, event, time, remark, etc., as pointed out or present, mentioned before, supposed to be
>   understood, or by way of emphasis): That is her mother. After that we
>   saw each other.

The previous sentence set up a hypothetical, "If you offered to pay me $100,000 to dust my blinds" and your problem sentence suggests that, in general, nobody is actually going to do it, so there's no need to pay serious attention to it.